How few cards in a suit would still allow a responder to make a "transfer" bid?
Both sides vulnerable at matchpoints.  Partner deals and bid 1NT (15-17). Right hand opponent passes.
In a dialog surrounding an earlier version of this question, it was established that it made sense for responder to bid two spades, asking for a transfer to three clubs (up two levels) with a hand as weak as ♠Q85  ♡ 8762 ♢J, ♣97432 that had five clubs.
Suppose responder's hand had a four card major. Would it then make sense for responder to bid two hearts, asking for a spade transfer with ♠Q852  ♡ 8762 ♢J, ♣9743? You have one fewer "trump" but the bidding is also one level lower. There is a small chance that you will end up in a six card fit if opener has only two, but most of the time it will be seven, or even eight cards.

You have it backwards.  The worse your hand, and the worse your club suit (in terms of high card strength, not length), the more likely you are to want to transfer to clubs.  Suppose your partner has a solid 1N opener like Axx Axxx Axx Kxx.  If your hand is xxx xx xxx AQxxx you are likely to make 8 tricks in notrump and in clubs, so you want to play 1N.  On the other hand, if your hand is xxx xx xxx xxxxx then you are looking at 3 tricks in notrump (can't get to the weak hand for the finesse) and 5.5 in clubs, and it's worth it to transfer.

@AlexanderWoo: The way you present it, we'll make 5.5 tricks at three clubs, going down 3.5. If I leave partner in 1NT, we'll make 3.5 and go down 3.5 tricks there. Looks to me like '"six of one, half a dozen of the other."

See the edit - you really only make 3 at 1N.

@AlexanderWoo: Based on your comments, I "turned the question around the other way."

I think the question's still wrong. Transfers are for finding good contracts. When you haven't got enough cards for a transfer (or crawling stayman) you'll pass 1NT and wait until opponents double you. Only then will you consider falling back to natural suits (2c, 2d, etc) using your chosen escape method. Why gamble and force yourself up to 3C (vulnerable, doubled!!) when you can play in just 2C, etc. knowing you have a 7+ card fit?

The point of playing in a suit contract is so that your little cards in the trump suit become tricks, if that hand has more trumps than anyone else.  With a 4 card trump suit, even in a 7 card fit, it's likely that one of the defenders has 4 in the trump suit and so the little cards in that suit are no longer your tricks (because defenders can draw trump)

@AlexanderWoo: If you are correct on all counts, that fifth trump may make a difference of TWO tricks, not one.( I had hypothesized a linear relationship; one more trump, one more level.) Based on your observations, the transfer works relatively well for a five card suit, but its efficacy "falls off" when the number of trumps drops to four

There's nothing special about "transfer" bids over 1NT that differentiate them from bidding the suit directly, as far as safety is concerned.
Obviously, transfers allow a second bid after the transfer is accepted, which leads to more sequences; transfers allow the NT opener to play the hand (which, with a strong NT, is frequently an advantage),... but as far as "why would I play in the suit instead of 1NT", it doesn't matter whether you're bidding 2♦ to play 2♥ or if you're bidding 2♥ which partner must pass.
So, the question is: "how weak can your suit be to still prefer playing in the suit to playing 1NT?"  And also, "are there better ways to get to a 'better contract than 1NT'?"
Normally, a 5-2 major fit (that could be 5-3 or better, but assume the worst) will play better in 2 of that suit than in 1NT, more often than not.  There are two reasons for this:

long trumps always take tricks; in 1NT you have to have an entry to them after establishing them.
long trumps also are stoppers for their long suits; in 1NT only high cards count.

As you can see, in both of those cases, we're concerned about the hands where responder is not strong (so no guaranteed outside entries, and few stoppers/help stoppers).  Hands where responder has some strength, we will transfer and invite (or bid game) in NT with only 5, because with values that expect to make 8 or 9 tricks, you will really only see better results (most often) with the magic 5-3 fit.  Note: this is a major blind spot for many weak(er) players - they transfer and invite in their suit with only 5, and do not understand why that's wrong.
Now, remember also that standard systems(*) can not play in 2 of a minor directly; the cheapest place to play in a minor is the 3 level.  Now, your suit has to be worth 2 more tricks than in NT just to break even.  Usually, with no outside cards, that would be a 6-card suit, but the hand in the OP is so bad that even the 5-and-a-singleton expects to take 2+ clubs if trumps, and zero in NT.
But that is an exception - with even ♠Kxx instead of Qxx, or ♠QJx ♦x, there's a chance that the clubs might set up and be runnable, or at least, helps partner's suit run or blocks the opponents' second suit.  If it does, 1NT may make, or at worst be off 1, but 3♣ only makes one more trick and scores worse.
Having said that, there's a better call with your 4=4=1=4 than transferring; Stayman.  Yes, if partner bids 2♦ you'll not be happy (and you'll probably fake being 4=5 in the majors and bid 2♥), but you will get to a 4-4 fit if you have one.
In the comments, we have "wait for the opponents to double, and run then".  And yes, that frequently works - you get to play the 4-3 or 4-4 fit with the ruffs from the singleton.  In 2♠ doubled rather than 1NT doubled.  And that's 200, vulnerable, even off 1.  If you Stayman right away, they might bid, they might not double you - they might not be able to double Stayman with "cards" the way they can double 1NT.
Remember, the best result with this bad a hand opposite 1NT is that they play the 20-20 misfit; after that is playing a fit and hopefully making it; then playing a fit that goes down; then playing 1NT that certainly goes down.  200 is called the Matchpoint Death Score for a reason.
(*)Having said that, the worst suit I have ever transferred into was ♦8xx.  Now, there were several special situations that applied:

We were playing a 12-14 NT.
I had a 2 count.
I could make a 2♣ call that "may want to play 2♦, or may have one of several invitational or GF hands, with or without diamonds."
It was in a Swiss Teams match against either the best or second best pair in the room, who I knew played penalty doubles of 1NT in balance; but again, might not have a "cards" double of our Keri 2♣ call.

It could have gone for numbers, sure; but I knew we were -800 or more wherever  we played it after LHO got to double 1NT; it was possible we could get out undoubled if I bid now.  (LHO decided to overcall my 2♣, and got to 3NT for -1 when she played it better than our teammates did.)

With Stayman, you need eight or more high card points to make it viable, because it'shard to stop at the two level. With a transfer, such a stop is much easier, and you cn do it with zero high card points.

1NT-2C; 2D-2H; pass.  Standard way to show a weak 4=5 in the majors for ever (by that I mean that the change was done (but still asked about) when I was learning in 1995).  Yes, originally there was the concept of "strong stayman" where the 2H call was forcing, but I don't remember the last pair who played it that way.
